# C# Wrapping and initializing multiple into an interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I have a api controller as below:

```
 public class ValuesController : Controller
 {
     private static string dynamoDbTable = string.Empty;        
     private IDynamoDbClientInitialization _clientAccessor;

    public ValuesController(IOptions<Dictionary<string, string>> appSettings, IDynamoDbClientInitialization clientAccessor)
    {
        var vals = appSettings.Value;            
        dynamoDbTable = vals["dynamoDbTable"];                   
        _clientAccessor = clientAccessor;
    }

    [HttpGet("data")]
    public async Task<List<MyData>> GetData()
    {      
        List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        var response = await _clientAccessor.GetContext().ScanAsync<MyData>(conditions, AWSHelperMethods.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(dynamoDbTable)).GetRemainingAsync();
        return response.ToList();
    }  
}
```

Also I have my helper class as:

```
public static class AWSHelperMethods
{        
    public static BasicAWSCredentials SetAwsCredentials(string awsId, string awsPassword)
    {
        var creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId, awsPassword);
        return creds;
    }

    public static AmazonDynamoDBClient GetDynamoDbClient(BasicAWSCredentials creds, RegionEndpoint awsDynamoDbRegion)
    {
        var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(creds, awsDynamoDbRegion);
        return client;
    }

    public static DynamoDBContext GetDynamoDbContext(AmazonDynamoDBClient client)
    {
        var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
        return context;
    }

    public static DynamoDBOperationConfig GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(string dynamoDbTable)
    {
        DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig() { OverrideTableName = dynamoDbTable };
          return config;
    }   
}
```

My IDynamoDbClientInitialization is as:

```
public interface IDynamoDbClientInitialization
{
    DynamoDBContext GetContext();
}


public class DynamoDbClientInitialization : IDynamoDbClientInitialization
{
    private readonly DynamoDbClientSettings settings;
    private DynamoDBContext _awsContext;

    public DynamoDbClientInitialization(IOptions<DynamoDbClientSettings> options)
    {
        settings = options?.Value;
    }

    public DynamoDBContext GetContext()
    {         
        //Check is context already exists. If not create a new one.
        if(_awsContext != null)
        {
            return _awsContext;
        }
        else
        {                
            var creds = AWSHelperMethods.SetAwsCredentials(settings.Id, settings.Password);
            var dynamoClient = AWSHelperMethods.GetDynamoDbClient(creds, settings.Region);
            _awsContext = AWSHelperMethods.GetDynamoDbContext(dynamoClient);

            return _awsContext;
        }

    }
}
```

And finally my startup is as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton<IDynamoDbClientInitialization, DynamoDbClientInitialization>();
    services.Configure<DynamoDbClientSettings>(c =>
    {
        c.Id = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:awsId");
        c.Password = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:awsPassword"); 
        c.Region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:dynamoDbRegion")); 
    });     
}
```

Now I created the above code without taking into consideration of Interfaces. Now I need to write unit test cases for this so wanted to know how can I create a single class and wrap up all the above
code instead of creating multiple classes like DynamoDbClientInitialization and Helper class. So that instead of initializing each and every class I just initialize a single class say "DbManager" that handles everything above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IoC Container. (See [comparison here](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison)), IoC Containers can resolve needed services automatically. Let's assume that we have interfaces `IA`, `IB`, `IC` and classes `A`, `B`, `C` implementing them:

```
public class A : IA
{
    ...
}

public class B : IB
{
    private readonly IA _a;

    public B(IA a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    ...
}

public class C : IC
{
    private readonly IB _b;

    public C(IB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you would initialize the container with (the details differ between different implementations, but this gives you an idea):

```
public static ISomeContainer Container { get; } = container = new SomeContainer();

...

container.Register<IA, A>();
container.Register<IB, B>();
container.Register<IC, C>();
```

You can also specify that you want services to be created as singletons. E.g.

```
container.Register<IB, B>().AsSingleton();
```

Now you can get a service with

```
var myC = container.Resolve<IC>();
```

Now the container automatically creates an `A` object, then creates a `B` object using the first object as constructor argument. Finally, it creates and returns a `C` object using the `B` object as constructor argument.

This means that you can have different classes implementing the same interface, but having different types and numbers of constructor parameters, and the IoC resolves all these parameters automatically.

You can also register different classes for the same interface using a key that you can specify when resolving a service.

Comment: Thanks.  I have to try this out to see if we can refactor to this. Would there be any implementation without ioc. Since I am using .net core any implementation that could involve using a single class initialization and using dependency injection in my startup class

Comment: An IoC just automates DI. Instead of working with concrete types like `AmazonDynamoDBClient` and `BasicAWSCredentials` it would help to work with interfaces like `IDBClient` and `ICredentials` and then to turn the static helper class into a non static one and to let it implement an interface `IDBHelperFactory`. This would add flexibility and the change to do everything with less classes. An IoC can help to wire everything together and copes with injecting different types of services.